# SPARQL filter xsd:Date fails

Tags: sparql, ontology

I have the following SPARQL query

```
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT DISTINCT ?d
WHERE { GRAPH <https:/my/triples>{
        ?s <http://my/ontology/v1.0#hasTimestamp> ?d . 
        FILTER(?d > "1945-01-01"^^xsd:date)
        }
}
```

When i execute the above, it fails to filter correctly the results by date. Actually it gives me no results at all, and no errors.

If i remove the date filter i get this response:

> ```
> "bindings": [
>   {
>     "s": { "type": "uri" , "value": "seo:S2A_MSI_2019_11_28_09_33_31_T33SXB_t_dogliotti" } ,
>     "d": { "datatype": "xsd:date" , "type": "typed-literal" , "value": "2019-11-28" }
>   }
> ```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can't see `xsd:date` here: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#operandDataTypes. Try to cast `?d` to `xsd:dateTime` in your query and compare with `"1945-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime`. What is your triplestore?

Comment: @StanislavKralin The triplestore is Parliament. I tried to cast dateTime like this:
        FILTER(xsd:dateTime(?d) > '1945-01-16T00:00:00Z'^^xsd:dateTime)  
but still nothing

Comment: what are the values of `?d`? I mean, `xsd:dateTime()` constructor is from XPath and doesn't work with arbitrary argument types.

Comment: as far as I understand, it has to be i) either a proper datetime string or ii) two arguments of type `xsd:date` and `xsd:time` respectively.

Comment: Ok, I see you have two dates, hat happens if you just select the casted value: `SELECT DISTINCT (xsd:dateTime(?d) as ?dt) WHERE { GRAPH <https:/my/triples>{
        ?s <http://my/ontology/v1.0#hasTimestamp> ?d . 
        
        }
}` - does it create proper dateTime literals?

Comment: Tried all of the above but did not work. :/

Comment: Your query works well for me in 2.7.13.

Comment: True, comparison works for me as well with other SPARQL engines, even with different types: `select * where {
VALUES (?d ?dt) {("2019-11-28"^^xsd:date "1945-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime)}
FILTER(?d > "1945-01-01"^^xsd:date)
}`

Comment: In the results without the filter, it shows: `"datatype": "xsd:date"` -- in the JSON syntax, the datatype is a full URI "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date" suggesting the data contains a URI `<xsd:date>` (not a prefixed name).

Comment: The "s" row also looks wrong.  Please show the data.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the suggestions in the comments but i couldn't make it work properly.

I stumbled upon a post from 2011 (!!) that partially gave me the solution. 
The post is [here](https://pablomendes.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/sparql-xsddate-weirdness/) and it states that the below solution (aka. "stringifying" the date works only for equality

```
FILTER(str(?d) >= "2018") .
```

and casting to *xsd:dateTime* works for comparisons.

In my case the first solution worked for comparisons (including equality), while casting fails miserably.